How to make relay node receive mempool txs without becoming a spo?
I want my relay to receive mempool txs just like how a stakepool operator's relay nodes work (preferably in p2p), i have tried topology updater before but as people are moving to p2p, peers i get connected are not consistent (sometimes i got incoming txs sometimes no other relays connect to me).
-What im thinking is talking to spos to connect their relays to mine so their incoming txs would be forwarded to my relay, but i dont have anything to offer in return so i dont get much their attention.
-Or is it possible to create a bp node that have 0 relay, is p2p enabled, 0 pledge, lowest minimum ada staked just so it can be qualified as bp node. so their is no security issues since the bp i created have no chance to produce a block. Just running 24/7, will that be discovered by other spos running with p2p?

Pretty sure all you have to do is set up a stake pool with zero stake.

0 relay? Because renting 2 cloud compute just for mempool is kind of overkill for me

Probably your best option for the moment would be to run the topology updater script on your node. This should bring you a few incoming connections, enough to have the mempool populated with transactions.
You can also create a stake pool with just the BP registered as a relay, but this is not best practice. But technically you can do it, probably many people are doing it on testnet.
